# Pretty Print HTML in Ruby (or Shell)

Tags: html, ruby, xml, unix, pretty-print

Is there any way to pretty print an HTML or XML string from the command line on a mac?  Trying to do this in Ruby.  Any ideas?  I've thought about XSLT, and about writing my own parser, but both of those are pretty involved.  Looking for something already out there.

Answer (score 4):

**XML files**

> xmllint --format file.xml

**HTML files**

> xmllint --format --html file.html

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xmllint.1.html

Comment: @landon9720 (sorry for the bad formatting)
`output = IO.popen("xmllint --format --html -", "w+") do |pipe|
  pipe.puts html
  pipe.close_write
  pipe.read
end`

Comment: to read from stdin, use - as the filename: xmllint --format -

Answer (score 1):

Something like [Tidy](http://tidy.rubyforge.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

In shells, another option is to use [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) without arguments:

```
pup
```

XmlStarlet also supports using an HTML parser. `fo` is short for `format`. See `xml fo -h` for help.

```
xml fo --html
```

The main implementation of `tidy` does not support HTML5 but [tidy-html5](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5) does. `brew install tidy-html5` installs `tidy-html5` as `/usr/local/bin/tidy` in OS X.